# Detecting vector heavy PDF files

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have an automatic PDF processing engine. I have experience in a variety of tools like PDF-TK, Ghostscript, PyPDF and PDFMiner but this problem is stumping me.

I use Ghostscript to optimize PDF files. This works so far without problem, it takes the image files within the PDF and lowers the resolution and files size is smaller.

My problem: I now have to process extremely vector heavy PDF with gradients that even though are optimized are clocking in at 15-20 MB which is not acceptable in my situation. In addition to that they take a lot of processing power to render in Acrobat and do so slowly.

Do you have any suggestions on how to combat this?  I was thinking to count shapes other than text (but how I don't know). Based on that information I could raster the entire PDF, or better yet raster everything but the text.

Any help greatly appreciated!